# Is it possible to group xml graphic elements?

Tags: android

I have several images in xml graphic layout and I want to move all elements in the same position.

Is there any possibility to pool them all together like a group?

Answer (score 0):

Are they all drawables? You can group them together in a

- LayerDrawable so that they're all showed at the same time. one painted over the other.
- LevelDrawable so that you define a level for each graphic and only the one with the right level is shown. You set the level in the ImageView that is holding the LevelDrawable.